checking delivery status for kaps sms system
I am attempting to check the delivery status for my sms sending service: https://kapsystem.com/
So as per their document given here http://trans.kapsystem.com/readme
i got this http://trans.kapsystem.com/readme/4.0/sms-status-pull but the issue is that here the BaseUrl expect the api key.
Currently i am using username and password for sending sms and i don't have nay api key is their any other document or endpoint for kaps system that can allow me to check the status for the sent sms

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
